# Unknown @ rule: @-moz-document for Stylish in Firefox 61

Tags: css, firefox, stylish

I upgraded to Firefox 61 last night and my custom Stylish theme isn't being applied.  Looking in Stylish I see the code section has the flags

> Unknown @ rule: @-moz-document

The code is:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("outlook.office.com") {
.ms-border-color-themeSecondary, .ms-bcl-ts, .ms-border-color-themeSecondary-hover:hover, .ms-border-color-themeSecondary-focus:focus, .ms-border-color-themeSecondary-before::before, .ms-bcl-ts-h:hover, .ms-bcl-ts-f:focus, .ms-bcl-ts-b::before{
  border-color:red;
  }


._cb_l2{
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

._cb_n2{
  z-index: 10;
}

@U._cb_s2{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

  ._cb_u2{
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to replace the `@-moz-document` line with something that will preserve the style functionality?

Comment: If you're using **Stylus**, not Stylish, it correctly imports such scoped CSS in the extension's style editor: simply repaste (or click the "import" button explicitly)  and it will automatically create scoped sections with applies-to conditions under the code. Stylus additionally supports [usercss styles](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/wiki/Usercss).

Comment: It's even worse for Stylish, @wOxxOm (and everybody).  [**Stylish has turned into malware** and is now **blocked by Mozilla/Firefox.**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1472948)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mozilla [nuked `@-moz-document` rules](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=798137#c8) with Firefox version 61.  It's supposed to be replaced with [`@document`<sup>(link)</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document), but that doesn't work yet.

This needs to be addressed in Stylish.  It would be best if the Import tool parses `@-moz-document` rules to its internal metadata and then strips the text on import, IMO.

I couldn't find anything about this new Firefox breakage in a quick search of [the Stylish GitHub](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish), so you may want to raise the issue over there.

As a **temporary workaround**, you can set the `layout.css.moz-document.content.enabled` pref to `true` in `about:config`.
That won't clear the red error X in the edit dialog, but the script will work.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem with Stylish. It's just buggy. Sorry for the confusion - I didn't use it for more than a year. I've been using Stylus that has no such bugs.

Comment: @wOxxOm, GTK.  Stylish has been slow to respond to bugs and pull requests of late. I'll check out [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus).

Answer (score 2):

@BrockAdams is correct about the change, but `@-moz-document` should **still work in userstyles.**
The preference he mentions enables it *generally*, which Mozilla has disabled for security reasons.
This about: URL takes you to the preference directly: `about:config?filter=layout.css.moz-document.content.enabled`

From [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document#Browser_compatibility):

- Implemented with the vendor prefix: `-moz-`
- Disabled by default in web pages, except for an empty `url-prefix()` value, which is supported due to its use in Firefox browser detection. **Still supported in user stylesheets.**
- Disabled From version 61: this feature is behind the `layout.css.moz-document.content.enabled` preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit `about:config`.

Note that Mozilla's compatibility info for Firefox on Android is listed as: `?`.